# How to batch add images with similar name using jquery/ php

Tags: php, jquery, image

I'm adding images to a website but the amount I want to add would take a long time, is there a quicker way of adding these images and for it to automatically find new images if the file name was appended +1 such as image1.jpg, image2.jpg etc.

I am using PHP. Also thought maybe this could be done using a javascript or jquery loop, for loop maybe, im just unsure how.

```
                <img src="images/other/pic2.png"></a>

                <img src="images/other/pic3.png"></a>

                <img src="images/other/pic4.png"></a>

                <img src="images/other/pic5.png"></a>

                <img src="images/other/pic6.png"></a>

                <img src="images/other/pic7.png"></a>

                <img src="images/other/pic8.png"></a>
```

Comment: What do you mean automatically find images. A simple loop would let you add numbers to the filename, but that does'nt guarantee that the images exists, if that's what you're trying to achive.

Comment: I would be happy to modify the code accordingly, from say 10 images to 20 in the loop, but itll save me adding the appended image such as image100 manually

Comment: The answer below in PHP should be what you're looking for then.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good idea to blindly loop a curtain amount of iterations hoping that the file is there and is a valid file, a better way would to loop the directory of files, check that the file is first a valid image and contains the expected filename prefix. This way you can add as may images to the dir knowing that there be added without changing code.

```
<?php 

$img_path = './images/other/';
$prefix = 'img';

if ($fh = opendir($img_path)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($fh))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            //Validate its an image and get size, also check that the image filename starts with the $prefix
            $attr = getimagesize($img_path.$file);
            if(isset($attr[3]) && substr($file,0,strlen($prefix)) == $prefix){
                echo '<img src="'.$img_path.$file.'" '.$attr[3].' alt="'.$file.'"/>';
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($fh);
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Well judging by your description, doing something like this would probably be suitable:

```
$initialImageNumber = 2;
$endingImageNumber  = 9;

for ($i = $initialImageNumber; $i <= $endingImageNumber; $i++)
    echo '<img src="images/other/pic' . $i . '.png">';
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly! Tried to +1, but I have low rep sorry